# FileNotFoundException: Could not load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on a .net Core project, using the .net Core framework, I wanted to use DropNet package with .net Core so I added a reference to `net452` framework inside my `project.json`:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8",
        "net452"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Now when I try to create a DropNet client object in my controller class I've got an error:

```
      Error CS0012  The type 'IWebProxy' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
    You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.   Test3..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
```

Ok in order to fix that error I've installed `microsoft.netcore.portable.compatibility` package, and the error is gone, the thing is that when I do that and execute the project and try to get access to the View that I'm returning from the controller action where I'm using DropNet I get a `FileNotFoundException` :

`FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I'm having that problem only with that view, this is my Action Method:

```
     public IActionResult Test()
            {
                DropNetClient client = new DropNetClient("gsfgsgsfg438", "6ysgsgs234cf", userToken: "w5gdfgsdfg3434d4", userSecret: "239usfgsghsf3434wyqo");
                return View();
        }
```

The problem is that DropNetClient line, if a comment that line, the view is showed, but if that line is active in there, the `FileNotFoundException` is thrown...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, don't abuse the `import` statement. It is there to override nuget validation when restoring packages, to install libraries which are compatible (PCL which target .NET 4.5 and Windows 8/8.1+) but do not yet have the `netstandard1.6` target.

**Don't EVER** use it to force import `net452` libraries into a .NET Core application. It won't work!!! .NET 4.5.2 libraries aren't compatible with .NET Core!!!

You only have two options:

1. Don't use any libraries which do not support `netstandard`, `netcoreapp` or `portable-net45+win8`!!!
2. If you need some libraries that only run with `net452` and there is no replacement, then target `net452` instead of `netcoreapp1.0`

Comment: There are no other ways except the two (except wait until library of your choice is ported to .NET Core). You can still target `net452` and run it on linux (with limitations), then mono 4.6 will be used and need to be installed on the linux machine. But Mono has a few limitations and things you need to take care of (or use replacement APIs, like cryptography functions, which .NET Framework depend on Windows API which is unavailable in Linux)

Comment: I've tried solution 2 but there is a dependency to `SharedClasses` package I'm afraid that `SharedClasses` just work with `.NET Core`, I've got this error when target to `net452`:
`Error NU1001 The dependency SharedClasses >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.` 
 any idea of what I could do? I need to use that package too, any idea of what could I do?

Comment: I suspect your `SharedClasses` targets `netstandard1.6` (standardd when creating the new Portable Classes) which of course doesn't work on net452. If you don't use any new/funky API, you can lower it to `netstandard1.0` (which supports API on :NET 4.5) or `netstandard1.2` which is .NET 4.5.2. `netstandard1.3` requires minimum of .NET 4.6. For exact API surface, see the matrix in http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library